# Install odoo 14 on centos7

Tags: python-3.x, linux, odoo

Can you help me please as I am facing an error while installing odoo 14 on centos 7.
I followed the installation method from:
https://www.soladrive.com/support/knowledgebase/4996/How-to-Install-Odoo-14-on-CentOS-7.html

Below is the error message :

```
Installing collected packages: gevent, freezegun, ebaysdk
Running setup.py install for gevent ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gg85mn28/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/include/site/python3.6/gevent
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/
Complete output (104 lines):
running install
/opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_ssl3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/event.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/threadpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_sslgte279.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/resolver_ares.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/wsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/baseserver.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_ssl2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_socket2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/ssl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/local.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/socket.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_socketcommon.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/resolver_thread.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/monkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_util_py2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/hub.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/coros.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/fileobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_fileobjectcommon.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_fileobjectposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/select.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_semaphore.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/os.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/pywsgi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/builtins.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_tblib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/subprocess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/thread.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_socket3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/_threading.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/corecffi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/win32util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
copying gevent/signal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/gevent
running build_ext
Running '(cd  "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/libev
configure: error: in `/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/libev':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 516, in <module>
    run_setup(ext_modules, run_make=run_make)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 502, in run_setup
    **setup_kwds
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 556, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 305, in build_extension
    self.gevent_prepare(ext)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 302, in gevent_prepare
    configure(self, ext)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 196, in configure_libev
    rc = _system(libev_configure_command)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py", line 172, in _system
    return check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xinpfhbd/gevent_b5d673917b35412ea78c75e9d66977ac/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gg85mn28/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/include/site/python3.6/gevent Check the logs for full command output.

Thanks

Comment: It is said clearly `configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`, first you need to confirm what are the acceptable C `compiler`, usually between `gcc`, `clang`, etc, second, you need to install it on the machine, and make sure it can be found in $PATH

Comment: Here is the current error message : 'gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=566 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -DPSUTIL_ETHTOOL_MISSING_TYPES=1 -I/opt/odoo/odoo14-venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/_psutil_common.o
      error: command '/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
    error: legacy-install-failure

Comment: And this is the $PATH : -bash: /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/root/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: '/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied. it seems gcc is lack of permission to execute, `/bin/gcc` itself should have `x` mode, we knows `gcc` need to create/write files in directory, it would be nice to confirm does it have, basically 2 things, does it have the permission to run, does it have the permission to RW related files in related directory

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this like:
https://www.soladrive.com/support/knowledgebase/4996/How-to-Install-Odoo-14-on-CentOS-7.html

It helped me when I install odoo in centos